# Error 80045C17 when trying to login at Azure to manage account

Tags: azure, authentication, account

Everytime I try to login im my azure account (http://manage.windowsazure.com/), I keep receiving the same error 80045C17, and the error message says nothing more then ask my to try later.

I Tried Every possible browser and the same result comes everytime!

I use the same username to log at every microsoft service.

I can't even stop my sites!

How to fix this?

Comment: I know Azure's support page points here for help. But for this specific issue with login issues, you'll probably want to reach out [Microsoft Support in your locality](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/customer-service-phone-numbers) to get it sorted out.

Comment: Steve, I tried that, but until now no answer!

Comment: Powershell could be used to stop your sites or manage your services.  It doesnt require a login, just a certificate.  As an interim solution i mean.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by first signing in to http://msdn.microsoft.com and then go to https://manage.windowsazure.com . It is using your Microsoft Live login session anyway so you have to log in to anything Microsoft. For example login.live.com

I think it happened to me because the azure portal was currently opened on another machine with the same account. Make sure you always sign out when you end using the Azure portal.

Thanks,
Alex Vezenkov